Java virtual threads: generators / explicit "jump" to another thread
As said in the topic, I wonder if the API of Virtual Threads allow to "jump" straight to another thread we choose. By jumping I mean we at the same time:

park the current thread,
unpark another one (which is currently parked),
ask/suggest the scheduler to start executing the second thread straight away, using the same carrier thread.

The most typical use case for this are generators. We have a producer and consumer without a buffer between them and they don't work concurrently, but we alternate between them. In practice, the consumer "asks" to jump to the producer, and producer asks to jump to the consumer. See this code using Kotlin coroutines:
suspend fun main() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val fib = sequence {
        var x = 0
        var y = 1
        while (true) {
            println("Producing $x, ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            yield(x) // jump to consumer
            val s = x + y
            x = y
            y = s
        }
    }

    fib.take(20)
        .forEach { // jump to producer for each next item
            println("Consuming $it, ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        }
}

https://pl.kotl.in/3o7oyhGBw
The most interesting part here is that while the producer and consumer run in separate execution contexts, and they have their own stacks, everything runs using a single OS thread. This is not guaranteed by the coroutine framework, but is the preferred behavior as this way we avoid switching between OS threads.
Of course, virtual threads also can run the producer and the consumer in a single OS thread, but I didn't find a way to ask specifically for such a behavior. I tried creating two VTs and alternate between them by LockSupport.park/unpark, I tried using SynchronousQueue, and a few more approaches, but whatever I tried, producer and consumer were spontaneously switching to random OS threads with each iteration. I could force it to use a single thread, but this is not the point. The point is to use the shortcut: "park me, unpark another" or "jump to another".
Do I miss something huge here or this is not (yet?) supported? I understand contrary to Kotlin coroutines, virtual threads are not scheduled cooperatively, so they may miss some related functionality. Still, I think it could be pretty useful.
To give you a little background: I don't try to solve any specific problem for now. I'm just curious. My intuition says cases like generators could be much, much faster if sticking to a single thread and just switching the virtual context, but my intuition may be entirely wrong. I didn't run any benchmarks.

No, there is no API for this.

No, and it is against Java philosophy, I believe. You might want to have a look on virtual thread's Continuation concept, it is kind of a jump you are talking about, but not what you are looking for, I am afraid. Note, that even such a thing like fencing is more like an SPI, LockSupport itself is another example. VirtualThread is non-public class.

@igor.zh Yes, I think this is somewhat against the philosophy, because with VTs we are expected to not control the scheduling directly. This is why I think we can't require to switch to another VT, but we could at least weakly suggest such switch. Or even provide only a generic "park and unpark" operation, and in practice that would usually mean switching, but would not guarantee it in any way. Maybe I'm entirely wrong, but I feel such operation is important for performance reasons.

One of the main selling points of the highly appraised ForkJoinPool framework was the work stealing algorithm, and the design that allowed to avoid switching between threads or to do synchronization between them. It was designed specifically to stay in the current thread if possible and not switch randomly between them. Now we have VTs and it seems they do exactly this - switch randomly between OS threads. This is the confusing part for me.

I think I now see your point. If virtual threads are anyway get dispatched inside of Java and not by OS why not to implement such a "nice" feature as forceful immediate switch to a predefined thread instead of relying on various posts, signals and arbitrary scheduling. Is it what you mean? Cannot answer for  VT architects, but my wild guess is the intention was to provide a only a lightweight version of Thread without adding new and sophisticated, low-level features.

As for ForkJoinPool usage for virtual threads, I am not sure at the moment that it is work-stealing feature of it that matters for virtual threads. If you look at both VirtualThread class source code and the ForkJoinPool documentation then you'll notice that VirtualThread calls execute, so from the standpoint of FJP VT is a non-fork/join client. Notice that its scheduler member is of generic ExecutorService type, so any thread pool might be good for VTs.

Why should having one carrier thread switching between these two virtual threads be more efficient than having these to virtual threads run on two carrier threads on two CPU cores at the same time?

@Holger Because in one case we need to repeatedly park and unpark OS threads, which, as I understand, adds some delay and probably quite a lot of it. In another case it is simply executing a single-threaded code, without any waiting.

That’s not true. Most concurrency tools, like SynchronousQueue, have a spinning phase where they poll the status, before falling back to parking, so if the other thread fulfills the condition in the meanwhile (which is very likely for trivial example programs like yours), the thread will not park at all. On the other hand, parking and unparking of virtual threads does not come for free. It’s cheaper than parking and unparking platform threads but still not free. And in your scenario of always switching between two virtual threads you’re paying the price on every switch.

And that’s exactly the reason why one virtual thread eventually gets to run on a different carrier thread, because parking the first virtual thread after signaling the second takes so long, that a different carrier thread picks up the second.

@Holger Oh, this is interesting, thank you for letting me know. I guess in that case there is no sense in further discussion without getting some numbers first. I'll try to write some JMH benchmarks comparing: iterator (potentially the fastest), Kotlin's sequence/generator, 2 threads + SynchronousQueue - using VTs and platform threads. I'll return with numbers.

Measuring is a very good idea. You may include tests with -Djdk.virtualThreadScheduler.parallelism=1; this is the closest to your idea of forcing them to the same carrier thread you can get (the underlying F/J pool may still create more threads if it detects a blocked thread).

@Holger I created some benchmarks based on a fibonacci generator: https://github.com/broo2s/benchmark-fibonacci-generator I'm a little out of my area of expertise, however, results generally look reasonable. Making long story short: busy-waiting in VTs is ~30 times slower than coroutines. Waiting and resuming in VTs is ~150 times slower. At the same time VTs consume twice the CPU of coroutines.

I don't try to say Kotlin/coroutines are better than Java/VTs. It is kind of opposite - I believe VTs should be technically capable to outperform coroutines in this case. So the potential gain in performance is probably bigger than 30x/150x. I think the only reason VTs perform worse in these benchmarks is simply lack of some kind of optimization and/or lack of additional API to fully utilize the power of JVM and CPU. But I will be happy if someone proofs me these benchmarks are entirely wrong and I just don't know what I'm doing.

The question never was whether Kotlin’s coroutines are better. The question was whether enforcing virtual threads to run on the same carrier thread (like when using -Djdk.virtualThreadScheduler.parallelism=1) improves the performance, compared to the standard mode where virtual threads may run on different carrier threads. I don’t think so, as the price of synchronization is paid in either case. This is different to another language’s feature which gets compiled the code in a way that the JVM considers the result as truly single threaded. In theory, it could even inline coroutines.

@Holger, as expected, limiting the parallelism didn't help. At least it consumed less CPU ;-). But this is actually my point. The problem is not that we use too many threads. The problem is that Loom seems to not feature a "shortcut" to execute a VT directly in the current carrier thread, instead of pushing it into the full dispatching process. I don't think coroutines are much different here. They just feature such a shortcut. Depending on the case, coroutines could decide to either dispatch the continuation or execute it directly. Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but I think VTs could do the same.

Maybe I'll provide more benchmarks for coroutines. Both existing cases are internally compiled to something similar to iterators - producer is in fact executed inside the consumer. Consumer is never suspended, it just calls the producer repeatedly. I can think of something where both the producer and the consumer run beside each other and they are both suspended and resumed. It will be probably slower, but maybe we'll be still able to avoid dispatching. Alternatively, I can focus on other cases mentioned in the project: actor model or fork&join. But that would be quite of work.

What you (apparently) need, is the Stream Gatherer API which is in preview in Java 22. With that, I can rewrite your Fibonacci example to Java looking almost as your code but running entirely single-threaded without any multi-threading overhead. Well, not every generator use case would work that way, but at least the example does (and a lot other use cases do)…

@Holger Oh, this is interesting! I'll definitely look into it, thank you!
